# How do I specify attributes for a Html.TextBox helper while maintaining the value retrieval from ViewData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the Html.TextBox helper to create textboxes.  I want to set attributes on the textbox, which I understand is done using the following overload:

`Html.TextBox (string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)`

However, I want to maintain the functionality where the HTML helper automatically uses the value from either ViewData or ViewData.Model and I do not see a way to just specify the name and the htmlAttributes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[EDIT]  After looking at the [source code](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/), it appears that all you need to do is specify the value as null in the signature that takes a name, value, and htmlAttributes.  If the value is null, it will attempt to use the value from the ViewData.

```
Html.TextBox( "name", null, new { @class = "css-class" } );
```

Answer (score 8):

try this for razor

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "", new {@class = "css-class", @onclick = "alert('demo');"});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to supply the value from your model, you could always just use the standard HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldName"/>
```

Then you can supply whatever attributes you need in the tag.

Answer (score 2):

@Tvanfosson, thanks for the answer. It helped me a bunch today. I was trying to create a table with a row for every part in a list. I wanted to set several attributes based on each part, and you pointed me in the right direction. In case anybody wants to see the loop and how to set multiple attributes, here goes:

```
    <% foreach (var poPart in Model.myPartsList)
       { %>
         <tr>
             <td>
                <% var part = Model.PartID; %>
                <%: Html.TextBox(part.ToString(), null, new { @class = "narrowText", @id = part.ToString() })%>
             </td>
         </tr>
   <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.TextBox("Name", "Value", new {@class = "class1 class2", @customAttributeName = "attributeValue"})
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: It's work exampe adding custom Attribute in  @Html.TextBox