# How to access name of the current element in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I created a "partial view" in the `Shared` folder (in `Views`) and I've named it `String` with a `String` model.

So by the ASP.Net MVC roles all the `@Html.EditorFor(ModelThatIsString)` should be my created view(String.chtml). That is working correctly.

**BUT** I want to have some javascript code in this view, so I need the ID of current Property, I've tried the below code:

```
@model String
@Html.TextBox(null,"");
<script>
  var theTextBox = document.getElementById("??????");
  ...
</script>
```

How can I access that?

Comment: What do you expect `@Html.TextBox(null,"");` to do?

Comment: View the generated HTML source and read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492494(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: thanks @stefan but you missed the point, I know what that method is, this code just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `id` attribute for this `TextBox` on your own. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291274/how-do-i-specify-attributes-for-a-html-textbox-helper-while-maintaing-the-value) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok `@Html.TextBox(null, "")` is wrong. So the first property that you've set to `null` should be a string of the name of the textbox. So this won't work. You've also hard coded the value to an empty string (`""`), so you're editor won't bind.

**Ignoring all that** if you set a name in your text box:

```
@Html.TextBox("txt", "")
```

Your javascript would be:

```
<script>
  var theTextBox = document.getElementById("txt");
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: it should get the name of model. Like if I have 'public string ContactName{get;set;}' the ID (that you named it txt) should be ContactName